# adb server is out of date. killing... ADB server didn't ACK * failed to start daemon *

Tags: android

adb server is out of date.  killing...
ADB server didn't ACK
* failed to start daemon *
error:
error:
I'm using my phone to debug with android studio  . Debug over the air .
I can't ping from my PC to my Phone . Help me !!

Comment: It could be because of multiple adb. Do a symlink or set the path correctly. For my case, on my mac, one adb is at usr/local/bin/adb while the other one is the android-sdk directory.

Comment: Thanks. I solved this problem a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, i'm using MAC. What happened was my ADB wasn't pointing to android sdk and turns out i had 2 ADB!!! so this is what i did.

1. type 'which adb' on your terminal or cmd. If your adb is not pointing to 
   your android sdk do this.
2. type this  ' cd ~/ '
3. then  'touch .bash_profile'
4. then ' open .bash_profile '
5. Add the path to the Android SDK, platform-tools directory. Add the following to the file:
   “export PATH=$PATH:/Users/YOURUSERNAME/android/sdk/”. To be sure, open your android SDK manager and check your path
6. save the file
7. then reload the environment variables by typing ' . .bash_profile ' on terminal or cmd
8. You're done.

If you need more help add me on LinkedIn:  williamanputra

Comment: I know about that problem . I just killed server was running. It's done